# Сколько классов можно создавать во одном файле?

Tags: java, классы

Добрый день! Хотел узнать, в java я создаю класс вот так

```
public class Solution
{

}
```

По примеру внутри него могу создать еще кучу классов вот так

```
public static class Mouse
    {
}
```

Если убрать слово static сразу начинает ругаться. Почему я должен создать только со static? Что такое Static?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/18305/%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-java-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отвечаю на вопрос, указанный в заголовке:

Максимальное количество методов и интерфесов, поддерживаемое Виртуальной Машиной Java - `65535`.

[Источник (Java 8), §4.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html), а также [Ответ на StackOverflow (Java 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4342081)

---

Отвечаю (точнее пытаюсь) на вопрос, указанный на странице:

В одном файле может быть только один публичный (public (главный)) класс.

`public static class` в данном случае говорит, что вложенный класс находится в публичном доступе, то есть доступен из других классов. Убирая `static`, компилятор думает, что вы пытаетесь в главном классе создать ещё один главный класс, вот он и ругается. Можете оставить только `class` вместо `public static class`, на работоспособность не должно повлиять.

P.S. Что-то мне подсказывает, что выше я нёс полную ахинею. Если это так, то пусть другие участники меня поправят :)

Answer (score 5):

В одном файле можно создавать больше одного класса!

---

Главное условие успешной компиляции:
**! В одном файле может быть только один public class**

Может  быть несколько ситуаций когда в одном файле можно создать несколько классов и это не вызовет ошибку компиляции:

1)  Если не указывать для классов модификатор доступа вообще (оставить по умолчанию), то после компиляции будет создано столько файлов .class сколько вы объявите(без модификатора доступа) в исходном файле .java, при этом ошибки компиляции не возникнет.

2) Можно создавать множество внутренних классов (**inner classes**) внутри основного.

3) Можно создавать множество статических вложенных классов **(static nested classes)**

4) Можно создавать множество Внутренних классов-членов **(member inner classes)**, которые бывают  трёх видов:

- внутренние классы-члены **(member inner classes)**;
- локальные классы   **(local classes)**;
- анонимные классы **(anonymous classes)**.

5) В одном файле также можно объявлять множество абстрактных классов **(abstract classes)**

---

В общем, такая возможность есть! Но хорошим тоном является **1 класс - 1 файл**

Comment: Кстати,  если НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ для класса, в исходном файле, модификатор public,  то имя файла может отличаться  от имени класса! 

Если класс описан как  public, то имя исходного файла  должно  соответствовать  имени публичного класса в тексте программы

Answer (score -1):

Внутри класса Static не могут быть Статики. Так как статичные данные выгружаются в память.

Comment: Пардон? Кто куда выгружается?